# Find the gradient of lines joining the following pair of points.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

If, $Gradient = \frac{(y_2-y_1)}{(x_2-x_1)}$

And, $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2) = (p+3, p-3), (3p+4, p-5)$

Then, $(y_2,y_1) = ((p-5)-(p-3))$

$=((p-5)-p+3)$

$=(p-5-p+3)$

$=(-2)$

And, $(x_2,x_1) = ((3p+4)-(p+3))$

$=((3p+4)-p-3)$

$=(3p+4-p-3)$

$=(2p+1)$

So,

$Gradient = \frac{(-2)}{(2p+1)}$

$Gradient = -0.5p-1$

The textbook says $-2$, where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Why does -1/(2p+1) equal -2p according to you? And are you sure that the textbook does take a certain value for p?

Comment: @B.Pasternak - you'll have to excuse my limited knowledge here. I got it wrong and have adjusted, however it's still wrong; $-1/(2p+1) = -0.5p-1$. And no, I'm not sure - what would it mean if it did?

Comment: $-1/(2p+1)$ does not equal $-0.5p-1$ (take for example $p=1$ and you see that it's wrong). The slope of the line through these two points is $(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)=-2/(2p+1)$. This equals $-2$ if and only if $p=0$. I don't know what the exact question was and why the answer is $-2$, but this is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so this question gets answered (and if you are satisfied then consider accepting):

The slope (or gradient) of the line between two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is as you say equal to $(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)$. Thus in this case we find
\begin{align}
\text{Gradient}&=\frac{(p-5)-(p-3)}{(3p+4)-(p+3)} \\
&=\frac{-2}{2p+1}.
\end{align}
As I mentioned in the comment, this only equals $-2$ when $p=0$.

Comment: and the gradient is undefined if $p=-\frac {1}{2}$

Comment: @Karl Damn right. Forgot to say that.

Comment: no problems +1 I was beginning to wonder about the gradient  for different values of $p $

Comment: @B.Pasternak: Thanks for your help!